# How to assemble multiple byte arrays only once all are available

Tags: c, arrays

I have a system set up where my c program receives packets in this format:

```
struct HidPacket
        {
            byte packetCount;
            byte index;
            byte totalSize;
            char dataId[4];
            byte data[48];//max most likely 61 but using 48 for now
        };

received packet: (total packets) 6 : (index) 0 : (total data bytes) 128 : eChF
received packet: 6 : 1 : 128 : eChF
received packet: 6 : 2 : 128 : eChF
received packet: 6 : 3 : 128 : eChF
received packet: 6 : 4 : 128 : eChF
received packet: 6 : 5 : 128 : eChF
received packet: 6 : 0 : 128 : gFjI
received packet: 6 : 1 : 128 : gFjI
received packet: 6 : 2 : 128 : gFjI
received packet: 6 : 3 : 128 : gFjI
received packet: 6 : 4 : 128 : gFjI
received packet: 6 : 5 : 128 : gFjI
```

i am trying to construct these packets into a full sized byte array once all 6 of them are received but i don't know where to start. What can i use in c to accomplish this?

i was looking into using queues but those are not native to c, there are no key value arrays in c. Should i try and find some sort of queue lib or is there a better option to run my combine array code only once all 6 packets of the same id have been received. I also need to think about rouge packets that never receive parts too. I wonder if that can be handled in queues.

update:

Here is what i got working:

```
bool didStart = false;
int packetSize = 0;
int dataPackets = 0;
struct HidPacket packets[6];
struct DataPacket constructPacket(struct HidPacket hPacket) {
  if (hPacket.index == 0) {
    didStart = true;
  }
  if (didStart) {
    packets[hPacket.index] = hPacket;

    if (hPacket.index + 1 >= hPacket.packetCount) {
      char msg[6 * dataSize];
      char* cur = msg;
      for (int ii = 0; ii < 6; ii++) {
        memcpy(cur, packets[ii].data, 48);
        cur += 48;
      }
      Serial.print("first byte: ");
      Serial.println((int)msg[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the data arbitrary bytes, or are they text? If text then you could possibly use the standard string functions like `strcpy` and `strcat` (if you remember to terminate the strings first).

Comment: the bytes inside of the data packet are another data packet split into 6 parts. A data packet being a struct converted to bytes.

Comment: So no string functions then. Then the solution in [the answer by John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839392/440558) is the only way to go. Once you have collected all packets, and reordered them into the correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char msg[6*48];
char* cur = msg;
for (int ii = 0; ii < 6; ii++) {
    memcpy(cur, packets[ii].data, 48);
    cur += 48;
}
```

The above assumes there are exactly 6 packets and each is fully populated.  You might want to stop earlier if the message is less than 6*48 bytes, etc.

Comment: my current setup has constructPacket run every time a packet is received so i may find a way to use if statements instead of for but this is very helpful. Thanks. I also have to account for unpredictable start times (starting at say packet 3) and missing packets timeout somehow. I think using my char sigs should be able to help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_HID_PACKET 6

struct HidPacket
{
  char packetCount;
  char index;
  char totalSize;
  char dataId[4];
  char data[48];//max most likely 61 but using 48 for now
};


struct HidPacket * Hid;
int HidPacketIter = 0;

void resetConstructor(){
  HidPacketIter = 0;
}

void constructPacket(struct HidPacket * hPacket) {

  if( HidPacketIter = 0 || Hid[HidPacketIter].index == hPacket->index){

    memcpy(&Hid[HidPacketIter],hPacket,MAX_HID_PACKET*sizeof(struct HidPacket));
    HidPacketIter++;

    if( MAX_HID_PACKET == HidPacketIter){
      resetConstructor();
      /*TODO: Put your funtion which process 6 packet here. */
   }
  }else{
      resetConstructor();
  }

  }



int main(){

Hid = malloc(MAX_HID_PACKET*sizeof(struct HidPacket));
resetConstructor();
struct HidPacket * ReceivedPacketPtr;
/*TODO: Put your packet receiver function here and receive packets here then assign packets addresses to ReceivedPacketPtr*/
constructPacket(ReceivedPacketPtr);


return 0;
}
```

You may check the index values of received packets according to a history buffer (Hid) and if consecutive packets with same id not received reset the histort buffer index. And if 6 packets (MAX_HID_PACKET) received then again reset the history buffer hid. At that time you can put your code to there process 6 packet. I also noticed with the TODO for the parts you should complete or bind with your code or application.

Comment: oooh a history buffer :O

Comment: for 6 packet queue job :)